# Autofill only working for the first time React Native Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, autofill

In my react native application there is screens with forms during registration

autofill is enabled correctly as per the documentation

```
       <TextField
          onChangeText={onChange}
          value={value}
          label={translate('firstNameAsId')}
          error={translate(error?.message as TxKeyPath)}
          autoComplete={'name-given'}
          textContentType={'givenName'}
          importantForAutofill={'yes'}
          autoCorrect={true}
          testID="first_name_field"
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          onSubmitEditing={() => setFocus('lastName')}
        />
```

But the autofill only appears the first time when the TextField is filled and when navigated back the next time its taken the autofill does not show up in keyboard. need to trigger manually from the context menu.

This issue in only seen in Android